# Yin&Yang Initialization - Wait for pieces before calling init

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

Say you have a method that returns information in two separate blocks, like so:

```
@interface SomeObject : NSObject
- (instancetype)initWithA:(NSString *)aInfo bInfo:(NSString *)bInfo;
@end

- (void)someMethod:(void (^)(NSString *aInfo))firstBlock
       secondBlock:(void (^)(NSString *bInfo))secondBlock {
  firstBlock(@"a"); secondBlock(@"b");
}
- (void)ourMethod:(void (^)(SomeObject *object))completionBlock {
  SomeObject *someObject = [[SomeObject alloc] initWithA:aInfo bInfo:bInfo];
  [self someMethod:^(NSString *aInfo) {
    //
  } secondBlock:^(NSString *bInfo) {
    //
  }];
  completionBlock(someObject);
}
```

How would you initialize `someObject` and pass it back when both of the blocks have completed?

Assume that both blocks are executed asynchronously.

I tried fiddling with GCD's dispatch groups to solve this, however, it didn't seem optimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you need to create your `someObject` with the values obtained from the two blocks used in the call to `someMethod`, you need to create `someObject` after both blocks have been called.

```
- (void)ourMethod:(void (^)(BOOL initializationComplete))completionBlock {
    __block NSString *a = nil;
    __block NSString *b = nil;

    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
    dispatch_group_enter(group);
    dispatch_group_enter(group);

    [self someMethod:^(NSString *aInfo) {
        a = aInfo;
        dispatch_group_leave(group);
    } secondBlock:^(NSString *bInfo) {
        b = bInfo;
        dispatch_group_leave(group);
    }];

    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        SomeObject *someObject = [[SomeObject alloc] initWithA:a bInfo:b];
        completionBlock(someObject);
    });
}
```

This doesn't block the caller of `ourMethod` and it ensures the completion block is only called once both blocks are done.

This solution assumes the two blocks are run asynchronously.

Comment: That's similar to what I've fiddled with.. The major issue I had with this pattern is initializing the `someObject` from `aInfo` & `bInfo`. Not just calling `completionBlock(YES);` :)

Comment: Well the code `[[NSObject alloc] initWithA:andB:];` isn't even valid but that didn't seem relevant to your question about calling the completion block after both blocks were done. Please update your question and clearly explain what `someObject` is supposed to be, what the `initWithA:andB` method is, and what the two parameters are supposed to be, and how it relates to the calling of `someMethod`.

Comment: That works... What would you do different if the `firstBlock` contained multiple variables that all needed to be passed to `SomeObject`? Would you add more `__block` variables outside the scope?

Comment: What would be a better idea? To support any number of variables returned from `firstBlock` or `secondBlock`? @rmaddy

Comment: That's a whole new question. Follow the pattern in this answer for now. If you later think there might be a better approach to deal with a specific set of working code you have, consider posting a code review on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I think I posted this question on the wrong forum then. I’ll try codereview.

Comment: No, this question was in the correct place since you did not have working code. Code Review is for working code that you think can be made "better". Be sure you read their help pages to ensure you post a good question there. The rules are different than here.

Comment: There's a difference between "working" and well written code in my opinion, which is what I was looking for. Your solution will do just fine. It's just too much of a hack for me to actually recommend or incorporate in any of my own applications. Nonetheless, I'll turn to code review & I've accepted your answer since it "works". Thanks :)

Comment: Fully agree on "working" vs "well written". Keep in mind that my answer is based on your initially vague question followed by your updated question. Now your comments are about a further change in requirements. This well written answer is appropriate to your question as asked, not for what it sounds like you really need for your real code. A helpful suggestion for any future questions you post here - please be clear about your requirements up front and avoid updating them several times as people provide answers. It's hard to give good answers to moving questions. Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a semaphore, but-- in general-- making an asynchronous operation synchronous is a red flag indicating bad design.

Are the two blocks asynchronous in and of themselves?   If so, you could have `__block BOOL firstDone = NO;` and `__block BOOL secondDone = NO;` and check appropriately to see if it is time to call the completionBlock.  Still ugly and you'll want a synchronization primitive in there to ensure you don't hit a race, but that'd work.

If `firstBlock()` and `secondBlock()` are synchronous and on the same queue, then just call `completionBlock()` after the second is done.

Or, alternatively, if they are asynchronous and simultaneously scheduled, toss 'em on an asynchronous queue and then toss a barrier block on the queue that calls the `completionBlock`.

Comment: I like the barrier block idea... I'll give that a try. The `__block BOOL`'s are too ugly imo. Thanks :)

Comment: @bbum FYI - the question just got a serious update that might affect your answer.